# CurrentWorkItem.ID is correct or not in workflow script editor?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1, And I am creating workflow like start-->create-->Review-->publish--Stop.

I created and registered the class library, and invoke the C# method using VBscript (Script Editor of WF Tab) as given below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim workflowHandler
Set workflowHandler= CreateObject("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler")
If Not workflowHandler Is Nothing Then
Call workflowHandler.PublishComponent(Cstr(CurrentWorkItem.ID))      
     FinishActivity "Published to WIP"
End If
Set workflowHandler= Nothing
```

Is the above code is correct? I am sure I am able to create object using the below line.

```
Set workflowHandler= CreateObject("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler")
```

And currently I am publishing the current item only using the C# code, am calling the C# function as below.

```
Call workflowHandler.PublishComponent(Cstr(CurrentWorkItem.ID))
```

After publishing the item, I am finishing the activity using below.

```
FinishActivity "Published to WIP"
```

I have checked the above code directly in the server by hard coding the currentworkitem, it was working fine. But when I put the same code in vbscript editor, the item is not published.

Can any one suggest on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hardcode you might be adding the TCM ID directly so it is working properly, which means that `CurrentWorkItem.ID` is not the correct API call to get the Component ID. See Igor comment below to get the tcm id.

Comment: I think that provided code will return you process instance id which is not Component Id. Correct API call will be CurrentWorkItem.GetItem().ID
Note that GetItem method has optional parameter TdsDefines.EnumOpenMode.

Comment: You're right. That only gives instance id not the tcmid. Edited the response.